# I want to use the following command (PINC & B00000011) to read 6 different conditions from hall effect sensors

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I need help with this code. I don't understand why it doesn't execute all 6 conditions. I am using PINC which is PORTC (A0-A5) on the Arduino Uno to read in 3 hall effect sensors from a BLDC at the same time. I am just putting print statements in the conditions for testing, however the conditions are not being executed. Can any one help please?

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() 
{
  if (PINC & B00000011)
  {  
   Serial.println("1");     
  }   
   else if( PINC & B00000010)
  {   
   Serial.println("2");    
  }    
   else if( PINC & B00000110 )
  { 
    Serial.println("3");   
  }
  else if( PINC & B00000100)
  {    
    Serial.println("4"); 
  }  
 else if( PINC & B00000101)
  { 
   Serial.println("5"); 
  } 
  else if( PINC & B00000001 )
  {   
    Serial.println("6");  
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want this code to do, and exactly what is happening. Are any print statements executed?

Comment: Instead of stating “it does not work”, try to explain what happens and what you expect to happen. What kind of sensors are connected to the inputs? What happens when you try to read one sensor at a time?

Comment: Try adding `else` at the bottom to print the value of PINC to debug the issue.

Comment: Since we don't know exactly what you expect, I'll just note that your `B00xx` constants count "3-2-6-4-5" in binary, not 1-2-3-4-5 as you may have planned

Comment: Yeah sorry I should of made it more clear. I am trying to read in 3 hall effect sensors from a BLDC motor which gives 6 possible outcomes as stated in the code. I want to use bitwise & to execute each condition, I know this can be simply done by just saying e.g. PINC == B00000100, however this does not work with my application as I believe it docent execute it fast enough, the only reason I have put print statements is just to check if the conditions work or not, they will be replaced by e.g. PORTB once code is fully working  which are digital pins to the hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should study the C language bit more. An `if` statement is true if the argument is non-zero.

Thus:

```
if (PINC & B00000011) // is true if port C ls two bits are 01, 10 or 11
  Serial.println("1"); 
else if( PINC & B00000010) // is true if port C ls two bits are 10 
  Serial.println("2");
```

As you can see the second `if` is covered by the first one already.
you probably want this:

```
if ((PINC & B00000011)== B00000011) // is true if port C ls two bits are 11
  Serial.println("1"); 
else if( (PINC & B00000010)==B00000010) // is true if port C ls two bits are 10 
  Serial.println("2");
```

Even that is dangerous as between reading the PINC the first time and the second time it might change. Also you are using the same mask twice. Let's give it another try:

```
pinc_state = (PINC & B00000011);
if (pinc_state == B00000011) // is true if port C ls two bits are 11
  Serial.println("1"); 
else if( pinc_state==B00000010) // is true if port C ls two bits are 10 
  Serial.println("2");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have tested this and it works however I wanted to eliminate the use of having == and just executing the conditions with bitwise &, because when I use == the code works but not properly as I am trying to read 3 hall effect sensors from a BLDC motor at the same time, using == slows the code I think and is not fast enough for this application. Is there a way I could execute the conditions by just using & instead of == ?

Comment: @DanielBashy No, it is not possible. What you should do is to use a lookup table, since that is what you are basically trying to do already. Or at least a switch-case construct, as the compiler may convert it to a jump table, if optimizations are on.

Comment: sorry could explain what you mean by a look up table or a jump table, thank you

Comment: `switch (PINC & B00000111) { case 0 : .. case 1 :.. case 2: .. .. case 7:... }`